# Javascript html change url every second click

Tags: javascript, html

This is my website http://natjecanje.interes.hr/

and I use this code in javascript:

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
```

and this in html:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/kontrast.css')">KONTRAST</a></li>
```

And that change contrast of my website, this link works when i click it, but when i change contrast i want that the same link backs me to orginal style of my website, can anybody help me with that? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function swapStyleSheet(){
   original = 'css/stil.css';
   contrast = 'css/kontrast.css';
   var source = document.getElementById('pagestyle').getAttribute('href');
   if(source == original)
      document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', contrast);
   else
      document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', original);  

}
```

HTML

```
<li><a href="#" Class="Normal" onclick="swapStyleSheet()">KONTRAST</a></li>
```

Comment: I used this, and it's working, but thanks to everyone!! special you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
    var oldPageStyle = document.getElementById('pagestyle').getAttribute('href');
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    document.getElementById('myContrastLink').setAttribute('onclick', "swapStyleSheet('" + oldPageStyle + "')");
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" id="myConstratLink" onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/kontrast.css')">KONTRAST</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your sheets inside the function itself and check if the sheet has been swapped yet to determine what the new value will be.

```
function swapStyleSheet (){
    var originalStyle = 'css/kontrast.css';
    var newStyle = 'css/original.css'; // <- or whatever your filename is
    var pagestyle = document.getElementById('pagestyle');

    if (pagestyle.getAttribute('href') == newStyle) {
       pagestyle.setAttribute('href', originalStyle);
    }
    else {
       pagestyle.setAttribute('href', newStyle);
    }

    pagestyle.setAttribute('href', styleToUse);
}
```

In your html, don't pass anything into `swapStyleSheet`:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="swapStyleSheet()">KONTRAST</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function swapStyleSheet(){
   original = 'css/stil.css';
   contrast = 'css/kontrast.css';
   var source = document.getElementById('pagestyle').getAttribute('href');
   if(source == original)
      document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', contrast);
   else
      document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', original);  

}
```

This works for me, thank you @Think Different

And thanks everyone for their time they spend for me, you are amazing guys, i'm newbie in JS :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Jquery You can use toggleClass function in Jquery. Rather changing the whole CSS you can change particular class and do the relevant stuff.

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#" Class="Normal" onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/kontrast.css')">KONTRAST</a></li>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("a.Normal").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "kontrast" );
 });
```

Comment: No [tag:jquery] tag on the post. Anyway, it isn't just a class, but a entire stylesheet.

Comment: yeah but this is a problem solving in a different way. maybe he can get help to solve the problem in different way if he is using Jquery. Just look at this part  "when i change contrast i want that the same link backs me to orginal style " he can change the link by changing class.

Comment: *"orginal style of my website"* you don't know what is in his stylesheet. It seems to change all website style, not only the link style.